# Javascript weirdness between Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox

I have a piece of JS that is taking a number (seconds) inserted by php and producing a count down for the user. It works great in Chrome, but appears to always have a zero value for seconds_left in Firefox. What am I missing?

```
<script>
// variables for time units
var minutes, seconds;
var seconds_left = {COUNTDOWN};

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
if(seconds < 10) {
countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
} else {
countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}



if(seconds_left > 0){seconds_left--;}else{countdown.innerHTML = "NOW!";}  

}, 999);
</script>
```

Comment: a) show us what the PHP actually inserts there. b) Don't use `parseInt` on numbers

Comment: How do 999 milliseconds become one second?

Comment: Leaving it at 1000 milliseconds ended up having the timer lag behind the server time, I assume due to processing on the local machine. The php inserts a value of 0 - 3600. Like I said, it works great in Chrome, it appears to behave as though it is a value of zero all of the time in Firefox.

Comment: ..and why not parseInt? I want minutes and seconds to be a string, and this converts the numeric to a string. Win-win..?

Comment: No. `parseInt` does convert a string to a number - just the other way round. Only because of implicit type conversions you didn't notice anthing of this. You'll want to use `Math.floor(seconds_left/60).toString(10)` or so

Comment: Math.floor solved the issue; many thanks!

Comment: parseInt converts string to number

Comment: Hm, I still wonder how `parseInt` could have caused a difference between Chrome and Firefox.